# set session variable or local storage in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage, session-variables

I have many php pages which have different forms. I want to submit all the forms to a page called insertproc.php in which I call my stored procedures to insert the data.
However I am submitting the form data using jquery.Should I set session variables in jquery script after every form submission ? or can I acheive this with some other functionality.
**example:**
if I have 3 pages say page1.php, page2.php, page3.php which has one form each say form1.php, form2.php, form3.php. I have to submit all 3 forms to insertproc.php. In insertproc.php I have check from which form I have submitted. Accordingly I have to run that respective stored procedure.
Should I set some session variable in jquery after I submit a form say

> $Session['proc_name'] = 'insert_user';

and check in insertproc.php the value of the session variable to call its respective stored procedure.
Please guide me how I can achieve this functionality.

Comment: Session variables for sure but you should have access to `post`/`get` variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you submit your form with jQuery you can add another input field to your `<form>` element which says which form is it, for example, `form1.php`:

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="form1"/>
</form>
```

`form2.php`:

```
<form ...>
...
<input type="hidden" name="source" value="form2"/>
</form>
```

etc.

Then you can easily check in your PHP code where did the submitted values come from by checking `$_POST['source']`. No need for sessions. Actually sessions could be source of errors here - what if someone will open `form1`, not submit, open `form2` in another tab, come back to `form1` and submit `form1`? I guess session variable would contain value from `form2` instead of `form1`.

Comment: thank you daniel for your suggestion, will get back to you if its working